# C# Help on a loop.

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, while-loop

We have an extra credit assignment in my intro to programming class.  We need to allow the user to enter a name, how many quizzes they took, each quiz grade, and then calculate the average and then their letter grade.  What I have now is

```
namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int counter = 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Name:  ");
            string sname = Console.ReadLine();
            int numberOfQuizzes = 0;
            while (sname != "Exit")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number of Quizzes:  ");
                string snumberOfQuizzes = Console.ReadLine();
                numberOfQuizzes = int.Parse(snumberOfQuizzes);

                while (counter - 1 < numberOfQuizzes)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Quiz Score {0}", counter);
                    string sscore = Console.ReadLine();
                    counter++;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Enter another name or type Exit to quit.");
                sname = Console.ReadLine();

                if (sname != "Exit")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Number of Quizzes:  ");
                    snumberOfQuizzes = Console.ReadLine();
                    while (counter - 1 < numberOfQuizzes) ;     
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The loop the second time through is not letting the user enter how many quizzes they took.  Also I know that to give the grade I need a if/else, but where in my loop would I put that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My version of your code, little reworked and fully working.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int counter;
            double score;

            while (true)
            {
                counter = 1;
                score = 0.0;
                Console.WriteLine("Name(type 'Exit' to quit): ");
                string sname = Console.ReadLine();
                if (sname == "Exit")
                {
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    int numberOfQuizzes = 0;
                    Console.WriteLine("Number of Quizzes:  ");
                    numberOfQuizzes = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    while (counter <= numberOfQuizzes)
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine("Quiz Score {0}", counter);
                    score += double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    counter++;
                    }
                    score = (score/(counter-1));
                    if (score < 60)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Letter Grade: F");
                    }
                    else if (60 <= score && score < 70)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Letter Grade: D");
                    }
                    else if (70 <= score && score < 80)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Letter Grade: C");
                    }
                    else if (80 <= score && score < 90)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Letter Grade: B");
                    }
                    else if (90 <= score)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Letter Grade: A");
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Grade: {0}",(score/100).ToString("P"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing wrong is you don't restart the counter, so let's say if the first time user had 5 quizzes your counter is 6 and probably bigger than numberOfQuizzes so it never goes inside the second while loop (or if it goes it'll miss some quizzes if the number is bigger this time)

And what you have in your last if is unnecessary. So change this:

```
if (sname != "Exit")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Number of Quizzes:  ");
    snumberOfQuizzes = Console.ReadLine();
    while (counter - 1 < numberOfQuizzes) ;     
}
```

to

```
if (sname != "Exit")
{
    counter = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Samurai...
My recommendation would be to change the `while` loops for entering the quiz score into a `for` loop if you have learned that in the class. It will naturally remind you to initialise the value `counter = 0;` and will increment the value `counter++`.

From...

```
while (counter - 1 < numberOfQuizzes)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Quiz Score {0}", counter);
     string sscore = Console.ReadLine();
     counter++;
}
```

To...

```
for (counter = 0; counter < numberOfQuizzes; counter++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Quiz Score {0}", counter);
    string sscore = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

You can also remove...

```
if (sname != "Exit")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Number of Quizzes:  ");
    snumberOfQuizzes = Console.ReadLine();
    while (counter - 1 < numberOfQuizzes) ;     
}
```

... as the `while (sname != "Exit")` loop will handle the new input and continue to loop until "Exit" is the input. It's a good idea to re-initialise values that you use again so you don't accidentally use their marks on the next person. Do that at the start of each loop iteration.

Finally, as for grade, that should be calculated after all the scores for the a person have been entered but before you ask for a new name. You will also need to calculate the average before you can determine the grade... but if we did it all for you, we should get the extra grade. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: ");
        string sname=Consolre.ReadLine();
        while(sname != "Exit")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the no:of Quizes: ");
            int numOfQuiz=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int score=0,totalQuiz=numOfQuiz;
        while(numOfQuiz>0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the score for Quiz {0}",totalQuiz-numOfQuiz+1);
            score+=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            numOfQuiz--;
        }
        score = score/numOfQuiz;
        if(score>90)
            Console.WriteLine("A");
        else if(score >70)
            Console.WriteLine("B");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("C");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter another name or exit? ");
        sname=Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```